# SQL query (Change csv id's to csv name's)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this.

`select pid,deptid from table1`;

in which `deptid` is `varchar` and value like (`1,3,4)`

Now I have another table as `department(deptid(int,PK), DeptName)`

I want instead of get deptid from select I can get deptNames in csv.like

```
pid | deptname

1   | dept1,dept4,dept7

2   | dept4,dept9
```

What should be approach for this.

Comment: One deptname for each pid or comma separated list of deptnames per pid?

Comment: Oh god, another concatenation question, a minute ago I flagged another one as a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming below is your table structure

```
Departments

deptid  DeptName 
------------
1       HR
2       Accts
3       IT

Employee

pid  deptid
-----------
1    2,1
2    1
3    1,3
4    2,3,1
```

Try this

```
SELECT pid, Depts = STUFF((SELECT ',' + d.DeptName 
    FROM @Departments AS d
    INNER JOIN @Employees AS ei
    ON ',' + ei.deptid + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), d.deptid) + ',%'
    WHERE ei.pid = e.pid
    ORDER BY DeptName
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM @Employees AS e
ORDER BY pid;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb6ed/1)

**Output**

```
pid Depts
-----------------
1   Accts,HR
2   HR
3   HR,IT
4   Accts,HR,IT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.pid, t2.DeptName
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.deptid like concat('%', t2.deptid, '%')
```

Although one should point out, it is not good practice to store multiple values in a single column like this.  If you have control over the table design, you should change it so each column contains just one value.  It causes lots of problems, difficulty in joining to another table is just the first problem.

Comment: I really believe that you should state using bold font that this is **SQL Server 2012 only**

Comment: good point.  For Sql Server 2005 I believe you can do '%' + CONVERT(varchar, t2.deptid) + '%'

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way